# MongoDB Compass returns all rows when I run a filter

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-compass

I am trying to run a filter in MongoDB Compass and it returns all rows instead of the row that I am looking for.  I can run the filter on example databases that are similar to my database without any problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBivJ.png

Here is the code that I am using to add records and select from them.

```
public class NoSQLDataAccess
{
    // Create an instance of data factory
    public NoSQLDataFactory noSQLDataFactory;
    public List<dynamic> DocumentDetails { get; set; }
    private IMongoCollection<dynamic> collection;
    private BsonDocument bsonDocument = new BsonDocument();

    public NoSQLDataAccess() { }
    public void TestNoSQL()
    {
        MongoClient client;
        IMongoDatabase database;
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoSQLConnectionString"];
        client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
        database = client.GetDatabase("TestDatabase");
        collection = database.GetCollection<dynamic>("TestCollection");
        // Insert
        List<Layer> layers = new List<Layer>();
        layers.Add(new Layer { LayerId = 117368, Description = "BOOTHLAYER" });
        layers.Add(new Layer { LayerId = 117369, Description = "DRAWINGLAYER" });
        layers.Add(new Layer { LayerId = 117370, Description = "LAYER3" });
        List<Element> elements = new List<Element>();
        elements.Add(new Element { ElementId = 9250122, Type = "polyline" });
        elements.Add(new Element { ElementId = 9250123, Type = "polyline" });
        List<dynamic> documentDetails = new List<dynamic>();
        documentDetails.Add(new DrawingDTO { Layers = layers, Elements = elements });
        collection.InsertMany(documentDetails);
        List<FilterDetails> filterDetails = new List<FilterDetails>();
        filterDetails.Add(new FilterDetails { Type = "layers.id", Value = "117368" });
        foreach (FilterDetails detail in filterDetails)
        {
            bsonDocument.Add(new BsonElement(detail.Type, detail.Value));
        }
        List<dynamic> results = collection.Find(bsonDocument.ToBsonDocument()).ToList();
    }
}
```

I have been able to get the result I need with MongoDB shell but I have not been able to replicate the results in C#.

**Here is the solution in MongoDB shell:**

db.TestCollection.find({"layers.id": 117368}, {_id:0, layers: {$elemMatch: {id: 117368}}}).pretty();

Comment: Welcome @Tom, please can you provide some [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help clarify the issue.

Comment: It looks as though the released version of MongoDB Compass does not support $elemMatch projections.  Which is what I was attempting to do to get the data that I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a post that is similar to my question that works for them.  The C# code that I attached is how I will access it after I get it working properly.  I use MongoDB Compass to test finds/inserts/updates/deletes.

[Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)